# Configuring the Lift project for Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, lift, sbteclipse

I'm trying to configure a Lift project for Eclipse IDE. To do this, I carry out this tutorial: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/index.html

I arrived until the step of Configuring the Lift project for Scala IDE, and when I run the command >sbt, I have this error:

**D:\lift-lift_24_sbt-61d24f7\lift_basic\build.sbt:11: error: not found: value EclipseKeys
        EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource
        ^
D:\lift-lift_24_sbt-61d24f7\lift_basic\build.sbt:11: error: reassignment to val
        EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource
                              ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?**

I don't understand what I'm missing?

Comment: i tried the same instructions and everything worked fine for me. Can you please share your build.sbt, to find out whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered that error before, and the issue was that I didn't have the `sbteclipse` plugin installed. Try adding this to `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`, or wherever your sbt plugin configuration file is:

```
//Eclipse Plugin
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to rename the configuration file from .txt to .sbt !!